# How to download full git of Linux kernel?

Tags: git, linux-kernel

I want to be able to switch between releases/tags of the Linux kernel.

One can download latest kernel from https://www.kernel.org in archive tarball format. That page says also:

```
Protocol    Location
HTTP    https://www.kernel.org/pub/
GIT     https://git.kernel.org/
RSYNC   rsync://rsync.kernel.org/pub/
```

However, on https://git.kernel.org/ there are many repos and none looks like full kernel. Is it there? Can it be downloaded as a single git repo?

Comment: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree is my top Duck Duck Go hit for "linux kernel git".

Comment: There is `[browse]` on https://www.kernel.org/ page. ...

Comment: Right in the exact same page you linked there is [a list with a bunch of tarball links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPXTS.png) that should be right in your face when you open the website. Just click the one you like the most.

Comment: @KamilCuk, thank you! Interestingly mainline 5.16 (btw triplee's link) contains less entries than stable 5.15 - 8 481 144 vs 10 033 935. I guess to modify and rebuild what is used in e.g. Ubuntu I better use stable?

Comment: *However, on https://git.kernel.org/ there are many repos and none looks like full kernel* - there are many, some are fuller than others. :-) This is sort of the pre-GitHub version of forks.

Comment: @torek, from https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Mainline-Stable-and-Longterm-Kernel-in-linux "After each mainline kernel is released, it is considered "stable."", why mainline git contains less objects than stable?

Comment: Object count doesn't have any sort of strong relationship to usefulness or any other measure other than object counts. Each user's repo has however many objects it has, and that's all we can say about it.

Comment: @terek, interestingly `git status` produces at first glance same output for both repos and says "Linux 5.16-rc8", though stable is 5.15.12.